# Getting Navigation Errors Using Push State / Pop State - JavaScript Page Change

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-history

I have built a single HTML page website where the page changes are controlled by JavaScript to show/hide the relevant pages when selected.  I have been trying to make the browser history remember the state of the page, so I can use the browsers navigation for a site implemented this way.

I have set up the program to push the state of each page visited to the the browser history, and then `onpopstate` go back to the most recent state on the history stack. For some reason, the back button now works in the browser, but it's completely inconsistent.  Sometimes it will go back to the homepage and other times to the services page.  I can't seem to figure out exactly what the issue is that's throwing it off.

My JavaScript page change and populate state function:

```
function ChangeContent (page) {

var pages={"homepage":{title: "homepage"},"servicespage":{title: "servicespage"}};

//Show home page
for(var homepage in pages) {     
    if(page!==homepage) {      
        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='none';
    }  
    else {      
        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='block';
        window.history.pushState( { title: "EcoQuiet - Gasoline-Free Electric Lawn Care" }, "homepage", "/#home" );
    }
}

//Show services page
for(var servicespage in pages) {       
    if(page!==servicespage) {
        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='none';
    }

    else {    
        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='block';
        window.history.pushState( { title: "EcoQuiet - Our Services" }, "servicespage", "/#services" );
    }
}
}
```

The function I have for `onpopstate` is this:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {

var state = event.state.title;
var homepage = "EcoQuiet - Gasoline-Free Electric Lawn Care";
var servicespage = "EcoQuiet - Our Services";

// Change History State Display To Home Page
if (state === homepage && document.readyState === "complete") {
    document.getElementById("homepage").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById("homepage").style.display = 'none';
}

// Change History State Display To Services Page
if (state === servicespage && document.readyState === "complete") {
    document.getElementById("servicespage").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById("servicespage").style.display = 'none';
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeContent (page) {

var pages={homepage:{title: "homepage"},servicespage:{title: "servicespage"}};

//Show home page
for(var homepage in pages) {     
    if(page!==homepage.title) {      
        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='none';
    }  
    else {      
        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='block';
        window.history.pushState( { title: "EcoQuiet - Gasoline-Free Electric Lawn Care" }, "homepage", "/#home" );
    }
}

//Show services page
for(var servicespage in pages) {       
    if(page!==servicespage.title) {
        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='none';
    }

    else {    
        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='block';
        window.history.pushState( { title: "EcoQuiet - Our Services" }, "servicespage", "/#services" );
    }
}
}
```

in your code pages is an object. So to check for the title you need to check it as above. Try this out.

Comment: My page change function is working fine though, it's just the `onpopstate` part that has issues.

Comment: you are setting the display as block but you should first set the display as none for current page. then block for the previous page.